# Floating divs at the bottom of the page in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get 3 `<div>` 's floating next to each other at the bottom of a parent `<div>`. The floating goes automatically since I'm using Bootstrap `col-md-3`. I've searched on the internet for solutions, but I couldn't find any that solves my problem.

I thought I'd create one without Bootstrap and that worked like a charm:
http://jsfiddle.net/6vbpmkgh/

This was a simple set up but it doesn't work when I implement it in my code.

```
<div class="option-list">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 pakketten">
      <p>Test1</p>
      <p>Test2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 pakketten">
      <p>Test1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 pakketten">
     <p>Test1</p>
     <p>Test2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the middle `<div>` has less content, so this should be smaller yet still at the bottom. (see jsfiddle link for visual)

Comment: So,you want that on top?

Comment: @ketan No, I want it at the bottom like in jsfiddle but when using Bootstrap it's at the top.

Comment: that is due `vertical-align:top` make it as a baseline.

Comment: @Dmitriy It is still at the top

Comment: Vertical align only works with inline block elements, floated elements ignore the vertical align property

Comment: @Dmitriy Thanks, that solved it! If you want, you can add an answer so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vertical align only works with inline block elements, floated elements ignore the vertical align property**

use 
`display: inline-block`

**vertical-align: top;**

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}


div{
  text-align: center;
}
div > div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 250px;
}


div.small{
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="small">div small</div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```

**vertical-align: middle;**

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}


div{
  text-align: center;
}
div > div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30%;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 250px;
}


div.small{
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="small">div small</div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```

**vertical-align: bottom**

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}


div{
  text-align: center;
}
div > div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 30%;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 250px;
}


div.small{
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>div</div>
  <div class="small">div small</div>
  <div>div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed `.col-md-3` to `display:inline-block` and `float:none;`